# Is this linq update correct?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I gotta run a maybe one-time or potentially once every few months update on this table. Basically to allow other programs that reference to run faster.  I really thought this update looked right but it did not change the data. Is what I am doing wrong?

```
public static void UpdateMFGtoID()
{
     DataDataContext _db = new DataDataContext();
     foreach (VINPatternDecode vin in _db.VINPatternDecodes)
     {
         vin.DivisionName = GetMfgID(vin.DivisionName.Replace("~",""));
         _db.SubmitChanges();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, but its better to Dispose your resources, and maybe, depending on the amount of data (if its small) just use one SubmitChanges():

```
 using (DataDataContext _db = new DataDataContext())
 {
     foreach (VINPatternDecode vin in _db.VINPatternDecodes)
     {
         vin.DivisionName = GetMfgID(vin.DivisionName.Replace("~",""));
     }
    _db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The `using` calls the `Dispose` function implicit.

Comment: thank you. I have about 200k records. Do I need to add the primary key to the DBML. File ththat I am referencing? Or is dragging the table in good enough?

Comment: with 200k records put the _db.SubmitChanges within the `foreach` loop (if possible). There are some issues with the tracking of changesets, wich causes ORM to slow down with these amounts of data. As for the PK part: i can't help you there. I usually use CodeFirst EF.

Comment: i am so jealous. that is what i learn with and loved it. Now i have to use linq to sql.

Comment: @jackncoke: I hope you learned to `Dispose` your `IDisposable` objects as well ;). You should always do this, unless you really really really know what you are doing.